# Rails 4 + Custom Devise attributes -- ParameterSanitizer Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.12spokes.com/web-design-development/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4/) on adding custom fields to my Devise User model, and everything seems to be working fine for the most part. However, on occasion I receive an error when I try to sign out of my application that reads like this:

NameError in Devise::SessionsController#New

uninitialized constant User::ParameterSanitizer

Extracted source (around line #11):

```
9   def devise_parameter_sanitizer
10    if resource_class == User
11      User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
12    else
13      super
14    end
```

As I mentioned, my application generally works fine. Sometimes I am able to logout without receiving this error. It simply baffles me!

EDIT: Re-starting the rails server causes the error message to dissipate, however, I was looking for a more permanent solution.

EDIT: Full stack trace:

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in 'devise_parameter_sanitizer'
devise (3.2.2) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:40:in 'sign_in_params'
devise (3.2.2) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:8:in 'new'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in 'send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in 'process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in 'process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in 'block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in '_run__1105479583300404070__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in 'run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in 'process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in 'process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in 'block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in 'block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in 'instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in 'instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in 'process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in 'process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in 'process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in 'process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in 'process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in 'dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in 'dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in 'block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in 'dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in 'block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in 'each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in 'call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in 'block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in 'catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in 'context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in 'call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in 'call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in 'call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in 'block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in '_run__1611111079631103792__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in 'run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in 'call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in 'call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in 'block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in 'block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in 'tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in 'tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in 'call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in 'call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in 'call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in 'call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in 'call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in 'service'
/Users/joelbrewer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in 'service'
/Users/joelbrewer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in 'run'
/Users/joelbrewer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in 'block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Your stack trace shows the error comes from `ApplicationController`, but the `NameError` you’ve included appears to come from ` Devise::SessionsController#New`. In which class do you actually define `devise_parameter_sanitizer`?

Comment: `devise_parameter_sanitizer` is defined in my `ApplicationController` - you can check out the tutorial (http://blog.12spokes.com/web-design-development/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4/) I linked to for more information as well.

Comment: Note that files in `lib` are not always autoloaded, and especially are not reloaded when changed. Please check your `config/application.rb` for "config.autoload_paths". It should be an array that includes `#{Rails.root}/lib`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When the User class is modified and auto-reloaded in development mode, the User::ParameterSanitizer constant is destroyed. But User::ParameterSanitizer is only created when its source file is `require`'d in your sanitizers initializer.

Rename `User::ParameterSanitizer` to `UserParameterSanitizer` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in development and solved it by restarting my local server.

Comment: I addressed this in my question: "Re-starting the rails server causes the error message to dissipate, however, I was looking for a more permanent solution."